# Rails: destroy all but newest based on column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got an `Authorisation` model that has outdated duplicates in it. I want to delete all except the newest based on a `:provider` column in `Authorisation`, leaving me with the most recent `"linkedin"` Authorisation, the most recent `"facebook"` etc, etc.

How would I write that method? Something like this logically but it gives this error (`TypeError: can't convert Authorisation to Array (Authorisation#to_ary gives NilClass)`):

```
old = Authorisation.where(provider: 'facebook') - Authorisation.where(provider: 'facebook').last
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this one:

```
 last_record = Authorisation.where(provider: 'facebook').last
 Authorisation.where('created_at < ?', last_record.created_at).delete_all
```

If there is `created_at`. In other case you should get all ids except last, and remove records with id from that array.

Another way, is apply `not` to query. Like:

```
 Authorisation.where.not(id: Authorisation.last.id).delete_all
```

But it work for Rails 4 only, i think.

**Update**

This is better:

```
Authorisation.where('id != ?', Authorisation.last.id).delete_all
```